# NODEMAILER - Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have Nodemailer configured as such:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.notreforce.org',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, //true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        name: env.email,
        pass: env.pasword,
    },
    tls:{
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Nguvu yetu" <test@notreforce.org>', //sender address
    to: user.email, //list of receivers
    subject: "Email verification",
    html: output,
};

//send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,error=>{
    if (error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json({msg:"Email has been sent"})
})
```

But I get the error below

```
Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection.login (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:448:38)
    at C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:271:32
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:215:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1313:14)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\web-projects\Angular apps\TosEcommerce\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  command: 'API'
}
```

Have tried to replace the Key **user** and **pass** with actual value but the error still occurs. Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: I know you have also tested it using hardcoded values for user and pass. But did you check the values for user and pass that are coming from `.env` file. If they are correct  or not by logging them ?

Comment: Use `process.env.email` and `process.env.pasword`

Answer (score 2):

Similar code would work for me on my **dev** environment, but wouldn't on **production**. I guessed values from my .env weren't taken into account. So I've hardcoded values for `user` and `pass` and it worked.
I read that you've already tested that, so you might want to try other values for `port` and `secure`? These ones worked for me :

```
const transporterOVH = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: "ssl0.ovh.net",
   port: 465,
   secure: true, 
   auth: {
     user: "contact@mycompany.com",
     pass: "HARDCODED_PASSWORD"
   },
         tls:{
       ciphers:'SSLv3'
   }
 });
```

Sorry for being so imprecise, I just felt like sharing what worked in my case. Have a good day!